# Allow WordPress Users To Edit Own CiviCRM Record

Tags: wordpress

I think I am missing something simple. I would like for a user to be able to edit their own CiviCRM record after logging into WordPress.  I have used a Short Code for the dashboard but there is not an edit link on the dashboard.  I appreciate the help in making this work.

Thanks,
Steve

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not completely sure on how to do this. But in Civicrm you can create profiles. A profile has multiple purposes and one of them is an input form for editing contact data. You can then insert this profile into a WordPress page

Comment: Thanks Jaap!  I do this all the time in CiviCRM but need to figure it out for WordPress.